# randomly sampling of dataset to decrease the values in the dataset

Tags: r, random, downsampling

I am currently trying to decrease the values in a column randomly according to a given sum.
For example, if the main data is like this;

ID   Value

1     4
2    10
3    16

after running the code the sum of Value should be 10 and this need to be done randomly(the decrease for each member should be chosen randomly)

ID   Value

1     1
2     8
3     1

Tried several command and library but could not manage it. Still a novice and
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Edit: Sorry I was not clear enough. I would  like to assign a new value  for each observation smaller than original (randomly). And at the end new sum of value will be equal to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample data

```
dd <- read.table(text="ID Value
1 4
2 10
3 16", header=TRUE)
```

and the `dplyr` + `tidyr` library, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>% 
  mutate(ID=factor(ID)) %>% 
  uncount(Value) %>%
  sample_n(10) %>% 
  count(ID, name = "Value", .drop=FALSE)
```

Here we repeat the row once for each `Value`, then we randomly sample 10 rows, then we count them back up. We turn ID to a factor to make sure IDs with 0 observations are preserved.

Comment: but this doesn't guarantee that every `ID` would be included in the final output. OP hasn't mentioned any such constraint though.

Comment: True. Some IDs may not appear if you are only selecting 10, but if that's a constraint then it wouldn't be very "random"

Comment: What I think op wanted to convey, is that they want to assign a new value that is smaller than the original value (i.e. 'decrease the values') for each observation (i.e. keeping all rows) so that the new colSums is equal to 10... But it's kind of confusingly worded and not very clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, Yeah you are right I think I was not clear enough. 

What I want  (like you mentioned)  , assign a new value that is lower than original value for each observation (randomly) so that new  sum of value will be equal to 10. I will edit my question.

Comment: So is zero a valid value or.not?

Comment: Yes, some of the ID can be removed

Comment: OK. I've updated the code to keep rows with 0 counts.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this works perfectly